# WordPress .htaccess File & Password Protected Web App Folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress website installed and working correctly on my server.

I created a new folder called "billing" and put my billing web app into it. When I go to www.example.com/billing/index.php everything works fine and as expected. But as soon as I password protect that folder in cPanel and go to www.example.com/billing/index.php it directs me back to my WordPress website and I get the page not found error.

I think this has something to do with my .htaccess. I did remove all the code below and was able to access www.example.com/billing/index.php while it was password protected but then my other web pages on my website stopped working like www.example.com/about/ What am I missing here?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition before the others that excludes anything in the `billing/` directory from being rewritten to `index.php`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/billing/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```